# Allow targeting .NET Framework in reference projects with .NET 7 when on Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a cross platform app that uses WPF on Windows for UI and Cocoa on Mac.

So I've got a project opens a WPF window, which is dynamically linked to the main application (which is a .NET 7 project). When this is on Mac it will use Cocoa to open the window and the WPF project won't be compiled.

The problem is, when running on Windows, it gives the error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

How do I solve this error without changing the main application project to .NET Framework (it needs to be cross platform).

Comment: I would first try copying the dll in next to the exe and see what happens. If that still errors you could explicitly load the dll into memory using code.  I think you might do better with maui though.

Comment: Your code does something to force the WPF runtime to get loaded.  Thus dying on the missing plumbing.  Easy mistake of course, we can't see it.  Keep in mind that this goes wrong in the just-in-time compiler, so the stack trace doesn't yet tell you which exact method is the troublemaker.  The caller should provide a hint.